# PhpStorm 2018.1 - Failed to parse validation script output - php7.0

Tags: phpstorm, php-7

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I'm trying to setup PhpStorm 2018.1 with php7.0 interpreter. I'm not using XAMPP. I've installed Apache web server and php7.0 on my local computer. PHP is working just fine with Apache.

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies

$ which php
/usr/bin/php
```

I think I should add `/usr/bin` to the interpreter path, but OK button is disable until I select a file not a directory.

Here's the screenshot of PhpStorm showing error

[image: Failed to parse validation script output]

Please tell me if I need to include more information. Because I don't know what else to include.

Comment: Check `idea.log` (Help | Show Log in...) -- it may have additional details. Right now it's possible that PHP generates some extra warning that breaks the parsing of the `php -i` kind of output (e.g. because of some bad setting or extension).

Comment: What user are you running PhpStorm from? Same as the user that runs `php -v` in shell?